# The state variable declared in context is not persisting its value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a context state variable to store my token value when user signs in. And using that token through out my application.
When I log in, the token is console logged on the login page. But it gives empty value on other pages even though I am using the context in all the files.

**AuthContext.js**

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState("");
  const [authProtected, setAuthprotected] = useState(true);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        token: [authToken, setAuthToken],
        authProtect: [authProtected, setAuthprotected],
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Login.js**

```
const userAuth = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    Axios.post(authApi, loginInfo).then((res) => {
      setJwtToken(res.data.idToken.jwtToken);
    });
  };
  console.log(jwtToken);
```

After log in, I use this in one of my pages and it logs an empty value

```
const { token } = useContext(AuthContext);
const [jwtToken, setJwtToken] = token;

console.log(jwtToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page reloads, the context is recreated. You need to use a `useEffect` within the context to refetch the information from the backend and save the token in case you are saving to some cookie or localstorange.

Put the token in the cookie and when it switches pages, retrieve the cookie by `useEffect` to save again in context

Note: when you switch pages, everything in the context is recreated, so when the page goes to get something from the context, it will be empty